# I want to sort my array in ascending order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting

Array: (2007-99 , 2001-96, 2005-93)
Sorted Output should be: (2005-93, 2001-96, 2007-99)

Please help me out.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are storing dates like that? If possible you should convert to NSDate first, then add them to our array, and then you can sort them easily.

Comment: these are not dates. i have roll numbers instead and the marks corresponding to these roll numbers.

Comment: NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2007-07",@"2005-01",@"2004-09",@"2003-02", nil];
    
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"" ascending:YES];
    [arr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

Comment: Sorry, bad assumption on my part.

Comment: but its sorting according to the roll numbers and not marks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a custom comparator to do something like this. In the method below, I get the location of the dash with rangeOfString, then get the substring starting 1 position further into the string, then convert that to an int to do the comparison:

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2007-07",@"2005-01",@"2004-09",@"2003-02", nil];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(NSString *s1, NSString *s2) {
        if ([[s1 substringFromIndex:[s1 rangeOfString:@"-"].location + 1] intValue] > [[s2 substringFromIndex:[s2 rangeOfString:@"-"].location + 1] intValue]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        if ([[s1 substringFromIndex:[s1 rangeOfString:@"-"].location + 1] intValue] < [[s2 substringFromIndex:[s2 rangeOfString:@"-"].location + 1] intValue]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Comment: superb :-) thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort this using a custom block (note that I assume that all of your numbers are formatted correctly):

```
NSArray *rollNumbers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2007-99", @"2001-96", @"2005-93", nil];

NSArray *sortedRollNumbers = [rollNumbers sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *roll1, NSString *roll2) {
    NSArray *roll1Components = [roll1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSArray *roll2Components = [roll2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSNumber *roll1Number    = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[roll1Components objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
    NSNumber *roll2Number    = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[roll2Components objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
    return [roll1Number compare:roll2Number];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", sortedRollNumbers);
```

Output:

> (
>       "2005-93",
>       "2001-96",
>       "2007-99" )

Comment: This one is also working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your array like this :

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2007-07",@"2005-01",@"2004-09",@"2003-02", nil];
    NSMutableArray *marks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++)
    {
        NSArray *sep = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
        [marks addObject:[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"" ascending:NO];
    [marks sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

    NSMutableArray *sortedFinalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < marks.count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < arr.count; k++)
        {
            NSRange aRange = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:[marks objectAtIndex:k]];
            if (!(aRange.location == NSNotFound))
            {
                [sortedFinalArray addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:k]];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order that you can sort your array, the elements of the array have to be compared pairwise to find out their ordering. Your specific ordering is custom, so you have to write a compare method (e.g. named `compare:`) by yourself, and then you can use `[arr sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];` to sort your array.
Now the `compare:` method has to be known to the elements of the array, because each element uses it to compare it to another element of the same class. So either you define a new class for your elements that implements the compare method, or you leave them as NSStrings, buth the you have to define a category that implements the compare: method. 
The compare: method itself could look like this (pseudo code):

```
-(NSComparisonResult) compare: (MyString *) myString {
    if
        (self.the_last_2_characters_interpreted_asNumber <
             myString.the_last_2_characters_interpreted_asNumber)
                 return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if
        (self.the_last_2_characters_interpreted_asNumber ==
             myString.the_last_2_characters_interpreted_asNumber)
                 return NSOrderedSame;
    else
        return NSOrderedDescending;
}
```